# Tween sprite or uicomponent?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I need to move 100+ sprites from right to left, for example, a hundred musical notes will be scrolling horizontally should be as smooth as possible, having tried move s:Group component found it to be inefficient with high CPU load even after apply updateafterevent(). Is it possible to scroll a large numbers of sprite smoothly?

Using Flash builder 4.

Comment: are you moving them all at the same speed and direction?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a game engine for some time that uses `BitmapData` and its `copyPixels()` function to render extremely quickly.

The process is basically:

1. Create a `Bitmap` object and attach it to the stage - this will be your Canvas.
2. Create an instance of `BitmapData` that represents the graphics for your notes (sprite sheet type) - this can be generated on the fly using `BitmapData`'s `draw()` method.
3. Create a class for your notes that has a property representing a reference to this sprite sheet.
4. Loop through each of these objects and use `copyPixels()` from the Canvas to parse reference to the related `BitmapData`.

If you visit [my website](http://projectavian.com/) you'll see a little demo of what the engine I've been working on that does the above can handle - 4000+ objects.

Many objects rendering smoothly:
[image]

Comment: Wow! If the sprite will need to light up (red note) and reset (black note) by redraw, does it work as efficient?

Comment: well, your demo hang after it reach 50% cpu usage. Stage3D should make it possible but my project need to complete next month.

Comment: Yes, changing the x and y values of the rectangle that you parse through copyPixels() will let you grab a different portion of the source BitmapData (which should include a red and black version of the note).